# Custom Operation in generic list

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a generic list as follow

> var list = new[] {1,2,3,3,4,4,77,67,56};

I would like to remove the duplicates and take only single digit positive numbers and convert them into comma separated values.

i have tried something like

> var singleDigitValues = list.distinct().ToString().Replace(" ","");

Could someone help me to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Var SingleDigitValues = string.Join(",",list.Distinct().where(x=>x>0 && x<10));
```